# Is there a keyword or structure that marks Javascript program insertion point?

Tags: javascript

In C# and C++ program control begins at the Main() function.  I am wondering if there is equivalent insertion point for program control in javascript.  I am currently looking a code base that I purchased a license for and I am trying to reverse engineer what is going on in the javascript section of the code.

Comment: JS is synchronous... You can use Chrome Dev Tools to set breakpoints. But it looks like you have to learn your JS fundamentals first.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is processed synchronously (although the browser makes asynchronous operations that run outside of the JavaScript runtime possible), therefore a basic rule of thumb is that code is processed by its insertion point in the page.

Having said this, JavaScript has standard looping, branching and callbacks which alter linear flow and it has a concept called declaration hoisting, which must be understood because it means that the linear sequence you write your code it may not always process internally that way. For example, you may invoke a function prior to its declaration.

But, the simple answer to your question is "no", there is no special insertion point or program entry point.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for your response.  As mentioned in the one of the comments, i think ill have to get up to speed in js fundamentals in order to understand whats going on. Thanks for pointing me to declaration hoisting.